Bind DataGridView to an Array of Dictionary<string,object>
I'm trying to bind an array of dictionary<string,object> to a datagridview.
The dictionaries will all have the same keys, and the values will always be the same value type objects (with different values). So the columns will be determined (and named) with the strings:
foreach (var kvp in array.GetValue(0) as Dictionary<string, object>)
{
    dataGridView_StructArray.Columns.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Key);
}

So, row will be an element in the array, so each cell will be the object in that array element:
for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    dataGridView_StructArray.Rows.Add(((Dictionary<string, object>)array.GetValue(i)).Values.ToArray());
}

What I don't know beforehand is what will the dictionaries actually contain.
I want to bind the datagridview to this array, rather than load the datagridview manually as per the code above.
Any suggestions...

MVVM
In modern programming, there is a tendency to separate the data (= Model), from how the data is presented to the operator (= View). This has the advantages that the Model can be reused for other Views. You can also unit test the Model without a View, and if you want to change the View, for instance show the data in a graph, instead of a table, the model doesn't have to be changed much. If you want to change the Model, for instance read the data from a database instead of from a CSV-file, the View doesn't have to change.
To connect the Model to the View, an adapter class is needed, quite often called the ViewModel class. Together they form the abbreviation MVVM. Consider to read some background information about this.
Back to your question
When using DataGridViews, people often tend to fiddle directly with the contents of the cells. It is way more easier to follow the MVVM pattern.
Class Forms.DataGridView supports MVVM using property DataGridView.DataSource
Before I show you how this is done, let's get the access to your data straight.
So you have separated your data from the Form: your Form  has an object of your Model, and a property to get the data that must be displayed. Something like this:
private IMyModel MyModel {get;}   // TODO: implement, not part of the question

private IDictionary<string, object> DictionaryToDisplay =>
    this.MyModel. ...  // get the dictionary filled with the data that must be displayed

Alas, you didn't write what kind of things you want to display, but let's assume you want to display Products with a unique string Identifier, something like this:
class Product
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
    public int Stock {get; set;}
}

So your Forms needs a property that converts the dictionary into a sequence of Products:
IEnumerable<Product> ProductsToDisplay => this.DictionaryToDisplay
    .Select(keyValuePair => new Product
    {
        Id = keyValuePair.Key,
        Name = keyValuePair.Value ...   // access the property that contains the Name
        Price = keyValuePair.Price ... 
        // etc.
    }

Quite often the ViewModel is fairly small, and thus these properties are part of the Form. However, to make unit testing easier, it would be better to create a separate class for this. Use Dependency Injection to make it possible to change the Model without changing the ViewModel.
class MyViewModel
{
    public IMyModel MyModel {get; set;}

    public IEnumerable<Product> ProductsToDisplay => ... // see above

    private IDictionary<string, object> DictionaryToDisplay => ...
}

And in the constructor of your form:
MyForm()
{
    IMyModel myModel = new ...     // Create a new Model
    this.MyViewModel = new MyViewModel() {MyModel = myModel};

    InitializeComponent();
    ... // etc
}

Ok, so now you have your Model and ViewModel. Available, tested and thus correct.
Show the data
Using Visual Studio Designer you have added a DataGridView to your form, and created columns for the properties that you want to show in the DataGridView.
In the constructor define which Column should show what property:
InitializeComponent();

this.ColumnId.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Id);
this.ColumnName.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Name);
this.ColumnPrice.DataPropertyName = nameof(Product.Price);
...

You can also do this in Visual Studio Designer. The disadvantage about this is, that the DataPropertyName is stored in strings. If later you decide to change the name of the properties, then the compiler won't complain if you forgot to change the DataPropertyName as well. The constructor method makes sure that you won't forget this.
To access the displayed Products is a one liner property:
BindingList<Product> DisplayedProducts
{
    get => (BindingList<Product>)this.DataGridView1.DataSource;
    set => this.DataGridView1.DataSource;
}

Now to initially fill your DataGridView with the products, during event Form Load is also a one liner
void FillDataGridView()
{
    this.DisplayedProducts = new BindingList<Product>
        (this.MyViewModel.ProductsToDisplay.ToList());
}

Suppose that the operator can edit the displayed Products, and press the button Apply Now when finished:
void OnButtonApplyNow_Clicked(object sender, ...)
{
    this.UpdateEditedProducts();
}

void UpdateEditedProducts()
{
    ICollection<Product> displayedProducts = this.DisplayedProducts;

    // TODO: use Linq and compare with original products to find which
    // Products are added / removed / changed, and act accordingly
}

I separated the method from the event handler, so you can reuse UpdateEditedProducts, for instance after a click in a menu item, or after opening a file, or handling a dialog box.
By the way, did you notice, that using MVVM, most procedures in your Form are very small, seldom more than one or two lines?
By adding a mock ViewModel you can even continue developing the Form without actual data.
Some nice procedures
Using DataGridView.DataSource makes it also easy to access the current product and all selected products
Product CurrentProduct => (Product)this.DataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;

IEnumerable<Product> SelectedProducts => this.DataGridView1.SelectedRows
    .Cast<DataGridViewRow>
    .Select(row => row.DataBoundItem)
    .Cast<Product>();

Note: again: one liner methods! Easy to read, easy to understand, easy to test, reause, change

Thanks Harald for taking the time to explain the MVVM paradigm. But the key issue revolves around class product that you have suggested. All I can tell you is that I'll be receiving a List of dictionary<string,object>. I don't know what key-value pairs will be in the dictionary, but each dictionary in the list will be the same key-value pairs, just that each value will be different. Until I receive the data at run time, I can't tell you want "Product" is.

Hi I am not sure what data you had but I've solved it in C# windows forms (which I assume you're using due to the DataGridView) with some dummy data.
`namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
public Form1()
{
InitializeComponent();
object[,] array = new object[3, 1]
{
{ new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Name", "John" }, { "Age", 25 }, { "City", "New York" } } },
{ new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Name", "Alice" }, { "Age", 30 }, { "City", "Los Angeles" } } },
{ new Dictionary<string, object> { { "Name", "Bob" }, { "Age", 40 }, { "City", "Chicago" } } }
};
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

        if (array.GetLength(0) > 0 && array.GetValue(0, 0) is Dictionary<string, object> firstDictionary)
        {
            foreach (var key in firstDictionary.Keys)
            {
                dataTable.Columns.Add(key, typeof(object));
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
            for (int j = 0; j < array.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                foreach (var kvp in (Dictionary<string, object>)array[i, j])
                {
                    row[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
                }
            }
            dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dataTable;
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

}`

Hope I've understood the problem correctly!

So you're saying to organise the array in a DataTable which is then used as the data source for the binding. I'll give that a go, once I get the hardware that's generating the data up and running again (another issue outside this one...).

I've given the above a try, but the underlying array of dictionaries isn't changed when you edit data in the DataGridView.

I understand, I've just tried this now and I'm getting all sorts of errors, not quite sure I can help you any further. I hope the first answer got you closer though.

I've used the DataTable method, and then writing a convertor to/from the array of dictionaries. It's helped with making it easier/more readable, but it isnt't binding.
